# Twig Customizing field

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am fighting with customize on symfony forms for twig...

My problem is that I want a specific look and feel for a field. Here is the code :

```
class FormType extends AbstractType
{

    //Builds the form
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('url', UrlType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                ))
        ;
    }
}



{# Twig template #}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    {% block url_widget %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="input-group-addon">url</span>
        <input type="url" id="url" name="url" class="form-control input-lg" />
    </div>
    {% endblock url_widget %}

    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" title="send">
            Send
        </button>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But when I use this I have two fields in place of one.

**[EDIT : split in 3 questions due to on hold status]**

**[EDIT 2 : solution found]**
As the question is still on hold (and in case it's displayed one day), I put the solution I've found, below.

As my field is named `url` it conflicts with `url_widget` (I think) so I have overrided both the standard block `url_widget` and the full name `url_url_widget`. The code is the following:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        {% block url_widget %}
        {% endblock url_widget %}

        {% block url_url_widget %}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span class="input-group-addon">url</span>
                <input type="url" id="url" name="url" class="form-control input-lg" />
            </div>
        {% endblock url_url_widget %}

        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" title="send">
                Send
            </button>
        </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

***Another solution is to rename my field in my FormType, what I will probably do...***

Comment: Please split your question in several questions. It's recommended to have only one problem per question.

Comment: Yes I was thinking doing this first, but as the main problem is the same, cutomizing form, I did it in one question to group

Comment: Now that is has been put on hold... Thing I didn't know about it, I will split in 3 questions

Comment: As I don't know how works the "on hold", will my question be unset "on hold" automatically, or do I have something to do ? Thanks

Comment: You should have a link to **reopen** your question. Then there will be a vote in order to decide if the question will be reopened

Comment: Thanks. I can't see/find that link... :-(

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, in fact it's automatic: *Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening* Source: http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: Ok thanks! So let's wait

Answer (score 1):

1. Move out block "url_widget" out of content block
   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form
2. If you don't want escaping labels also use form themes
   [HTML in Symfony2 form labels instead of plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551735/html-in-symfony2-form-labels-instead-of-plain-text)
3. Options are translated automatically
   [Translate select options in Symfony2 class forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187984/translate-select-options-in-symfony2-class-forms)

Comment: Thanks for yours answers. For 1) I have tried outside of the block content or with `{{ form_ro(form.url) }}` but I still have 2 inputs. For 2) I have tried with the raw (even at diferent places), but the html are still escaped (I have added the code I use above). For 3) yes, but the problem is that my label contains numbers and results of operations with text, so the content is not only a full translation placeholder, i.e. 1 year -5 credits, where year and credits have to be translated. But really thanks for your help!